# Get "<Response [403]>" using request.post in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urlopen

I was trying to get search result from a website, however I got 
"Response[403]" message, I've found similar post solving 403 error by adding headers to request.post, however it didn't work for my problem. What should I do to correctly get the result I want?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url="https://www.metal-archives.com/"
html= urlopen(url)
print("The keyword you entered to search is: %s\n" % 'Bathory')
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result=requests.post(url, data='Bathory', headers=headers)
print(result.content)
```

Comment: If you try to hit the site with your browser do you get a 403?

Comment: The problem is not with the headers. It's with `data='Bathory'`. Are you trying to search for that word?

Comment: I suspect that they just don't want you to post data.  If you rewrite your script as a get it will 200.  However if you are trying to use their search, you need to do more than just post. :)

Comment: sniperd - No, it will show the search results, however results are not found in the html I get. I did get a 200 before, do you have any idea is there any workaround to get the result if they don't want me to post data?

KeyurPotdar - Yes, it is the exact word I want to search, it originally was a variable, to be convenient I change it to a string here in order to ask.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need the headers as you can see that you're getting status 
 code `200`:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.metal-archives.com')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

If you want to search for anything, you can see that the url changes to

> https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString=bathory

That means, you can directly format it using this:

```
>>> keyword = 'bathory'
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString='+keyword)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> 'bathory' in r.text
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check HTML you'll find that `form` method is GET (may be that's why you get 403 error):

```
<form id="search_form" action="https://www.metal-archives.com/search" method="get">
```

so all you need is to construct search URL:

```
#Music genre search
result=requests.get( "https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString={0}&type=band_genre".format("Bathory") )
#Band name search
result=requests.get( "https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString={0}&type=band_name".format("Bathory") )
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to HTML format, another thing is that there are real results shown in the web page below, however how do I find the information in the result variable by using requests.get? Is the page purposely hiding the information? is any other way to get it? 

https://www.metal-archives.com/search?searchString=Bathory&type=band_name